# ¿Cuándo crear un feature y cuando un release con git flow?

Tags: git-flow, metodología

Estoy trabajando con **git-flow** bajo la **metodologia scrum** y no se cuando debo crear un

> feature

y cuando un:

> release

si es por cada **sprint** o por cada **epica**.

alguna idea? o talvez la pregunta no va por ese tema?

Answer (score 1):

Independientemente de la metodología de trabajo que lleves (Scrum, Kanban, Cascada, etc) debes distinguir claramente los términos:

- Una **feature** (del inglés, característica) es la implementación de una nueva funcionalidad en tu aplicación.
- Una **release** (del inglés, lanzamiento) es un versión de tu aplicación que contiene tantas features, bugfixes y demás que se hayan solucionado.

Entiendo a tu pregunta que en un *sprint* (donde se proponen las tareas a realizar y se remarcan objetivos) se van creando tareas que pueden ser features. La entrega de estas tareas al cliente (momento en que se realiza una release) puede materializarse, según se haya acordado, al finalizar un *sprint* o una *épica*. Esta parte es más subjetiva y es según lo que haya acordado tu equipo.

Answer (score 1):

Si estas utilizando git flow con scrum podrías utilizar un **feature** por cada Epic, pero tienes que tomar en cuenta lo que es cada rama y para que sirve cada una

**Feature**: Es para una nueva funcionalidad y algo que después se va a sacar una rama de release

**Release**: Es la rama que después de haber hecho merge con develop se transforma en release, esta rama yo la paso a QA y luego le hago merge a develop y a master 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]